# Word to describe an absorbing activity which causes one to fail to notice the passage of large amounts of time

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, descriptive-grammar

The phrase,  "Time flies when you're having fun," is often used when one has become absorbed in an activity and lost track of time. I'm looking for a word to describe something that has a tendency to cause someone to lose track of time. I want a word that can be used similarly to something like:

> It is a very time-consuming activity.

However, I do not want the word to imply the activity necessitates a large amount of time. Rather, it should imply that the activity is absorbing enough that one spends a large amount of time doing it, without noticing if it's been a long time. I feel as if I know the word I am looking for, it is simply on the tip of my tongue and just out of reach. I'm sorry if my examples and descriptions make little sense. Any help is appreciated though.

Comment: It's not one word, but "zoning out on Facebook".

Comment: Clearly one such word is "*fun*".

Comment: [_Captivating_](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/captivating).

Comment: @ermanen If you have time, it's preferred that you post that as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: You own term *absorbing activity* works in that context.

Comment: to clarify: Do you mean an activity that distorts your 'inner clock'? As in: While doing X you _think_ an hour passed while in reality 4 hours passed? I have this with the Civilization games for example. I don't get 'in a flow' (which I know and get into while writing code for example) while playing it - it's just that for some reason my inner clock 'desynchronizes'. There are only a few games where that happens and I only ever had this happen while playing those video games.

Comment: In the context of ADHD, this is referred to as _hyperfocus_ - the tendency to become completely engrossed in a task for hours, to the point where all other senses are dulled (including interoception), with no perception of the amount of time that has passed.

Answer (score 39):

*Engrossing*, perhaps.

> **engrossing** adjective
>
> very interesting and needing all your attention:
>
> - an engrossing book/story
> - I found the movie completely engrossing from beginning to end.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/engrossing)

Answer (score 10):

The activity allows one to enter [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)), "the mental state of operation in which a person performing an activity is fully immersed in a feeling of energized focus, full involvement, and enjoyment in the process of the activity" (link and quote from Wikipedia).

For many, including myself, when I enter a period of flow, it is only ended by the sudden and surprising realization that I have not eaten, urinated, or performed other basic needs for that entire time, and out of nowhere they have become urgent.

Some games, a challenging puzzle, some tasks at work (I write software code) and such have caused me to experience this type of **flow.**

Comment: This is a noun, not an adjective.

Answer (score 5):

"engross" is the best word for it, as suggested.

You could also use the expression "to lose oneself in (something)".

Answer (score 2):

I may have slightly misread the question. Thanks to @Tiny Giant for the subtle prod :o)

As a word *for the activity*, a **distraction** and **diversion** are the most literal I can think of and I'd say both short and on the mark.

Both can be used in adjective form too - a ***distracting***, or ***diverting***, activity.

Comment: "It is a very distracting activity" works fairly well to articulate the OP's intent I think.

Comment: You're quite right - I'll update my answer :o)

Comment: I do think “[X] is a great diversion” is more idiomatic, but I guess that's subjective.

Answer (score 2):

**Consuming**, or stronger, **all-consuming** are common adjectives for these kinds of activities.

Per Google’s [dictionary entry](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dictionary#dobs=consuming):

> ### con·sum·ing
>
> #### /kənˈso͞omiNG/
>
> *adjective*
>
> adjective: **consuming**
>
> (of a feeling) completely filling one's mind and attention; absorbing.
>
> > "a consuming passion"

> ### all-consuming
>
> #### /ˌôlkənˈso͞omiNG/
>
> adjective
>
> adjective: **all-consuming**
>
> completely filling one's mind and attention; obsessive.
>
> > "the period was one of fiery, all-consuming work for Van Gogh"

Comment: Answers should consist mostly of your own words, not of text copied from elsewhere.

Comment: @tchrist How is this any different from any of literally hundreds of other single-word-request answers on this site that consist of a suggestion and its dictionary entry? Including the highest-voted answer to this question, at the moment. I completely agree with the premise but for single-word-requests there often doesn’t seem much more to say.

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic saying for this is [spellbinding](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spellbinding)

> Spellbinding : holding the attention as if by a spell